# amazon elastic beanstalk how to change RDS

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 2 different elastic beanstalks and want them to be connected to the same RDS, but i can't find any way to change the Eclipse RDS Endpoint.
I can do it on the PHP level with an if-statement, but i want to change the $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'] variable. 
Does any one know how to do this?